# Path-integral $ \int_0^1(|t|-1)^2dt, \int_0^1(|i-it|-1)^2(-i)dt$

Tags: integration, complex-analysis

I am working on the following tasks:
Calculate
$$ \int_0^1(|t|-1)^2dt$$
$$\int_0^1(|e^{i\frac{\pi}{2}t}|-1)^2\left(i\frac{\pi}{2}e^{i\frac{\pi}{2}t}\right)dt$$
$$\int_0^1(|i-it|-1)^2(-i)dt.$$
My idea:
For the third integral I got
$$\int_0^1(|i-it|-1)^2(-i)dt=\int_0^1(|t-1|-1)^2(-i)dt.$$
How can I handle $|t-1|$ in this case?
For the second one
$$\int_0^1(|e^{i\frac{\pi}{2}t}|-1)^2\left(i\frac{\pi}{2}e^{i\frac{\pi}{2}t}\right)dt=\int_0^1(1-1)^2\left(i\frac{\pi}{2}e^{i\frac{\pi}{2}t}\right)dt=0$$
but I am not sure whether $|e^{i\frac{\pi}{2}t}|=1$ is right.
And for the first one I don´t know how to start...
Any hints are greatly appreciated!!

Comment: On $[0,1]$, you have $|t|=t$ and $|t-1|=-(t-1)$ by definition of absolute value. And you are right that $\left|e^{i\frac{\pi t}2}\right|=1$, since$$\left|e^{i\frac{\pi t}2}\right|=\sqrt{\cos^2\left(\frac{\pi t}2\right)+\sin^2\left(\frac{\pi t}2\right)}=1$$

Comment: Should that first integral be $\int_\gamma (|z|-1)^2dz$, where $\gamma$ is the path along the unit circle from $1$ to $i$? As written it's just an integral over a real variable.

Comment: @eyeballfrog the path $\gamma$ in this case is just $\gamma:[0,1]\to\mathbb{C}, t \to t$

Comment: Oh. Then where is the $e^{i\pi t/2}$ coming from?

Comment: @eyeballfrog there we have $\gamma_2:[0,1]\to\mathbb{C}, t \to e^{i\frac{\pi}{2}t}$, the third path is $\gamma_3:[0,1]\to\mathbb{C}, t \to i(1-t)$, and the function is defined as $f:\mathbb{C}\to\mathbb{C}, z\to |z|^2-2|z|+1$

Comment: This is all good information to include in the question body, for future reference.

Comment: I will keep it in mind, thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So we're integrating $(|z|-1)^2$ over the contour $z = t,z = e^{i\pi t/2},z = i(1-t)$, where each $t$ goes from $0$ to $1$. So we have
$$
\oint (|z|-1)^2dz = \int_0^1(|t|-1)^2dt + \int_0^1\left(\left|e^{i\pi t/2}\right| - 1\right)^2\left(i\frac{\pi}{2}e^{i\pi t/2}\right)dt + \int_0^1(|i(1-t)|-1)^2(-i)dt,
$$
as you found. Let's go through the integrals in order.

1. If $t\in[0,1]$, $|t| = t$. So we just get $\int_0^1(t-1)^2dt = 1/3$.
2. $|e^{i\pi t/2}| = 1$, so the integrand is identically $0$, and thus so is the integral.
3. Note that $|i(1-t)| = |1-t| = 1-t$ for $t\in[0,1]$, so you get $-i\int_0^1t^2dt = -i/3$.

Add these all together to get
$$
\oint (|z|-1)^2dz = \frac{1-i}{3}
$$